# Need to share with non Blender users

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm on a committee to remodel the stage and platform at our church. I have our ideas modeled in Blender 2.80 and would like to share the final product with the team in a way that they don't need to have or understand Blender in order to view or interact with it.
How can I do this?
Thanks for your time and effort.
James

Comment: Does your model need to show materials? If not, you could use an online viewer like this one - https://3dviewer.net/. It accepts .obj files, which blender does export, but you have to color it based on the website's rather limited options.

Comment: Mmm.  Yeah, it really needs to have the colors and textures included.  The remodel is going to include painting, adding wood accents, lighting, as well as rearranging the piano and drums.  So far, I have just sent screenshots of different points of view.  I really wish there was a way I could just send them the model itself so they could move it around and look at it.  They are all capable of figuring it out but it would not really be worth it just for this.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way - take this example from sketchfab - it's from someone who's selling a model, but there may be a way to just upload it on it's own (without selling). - https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/stage-set-for-la-boheme-opera-50c524ec00934949bd94b5afc7cb2e94. Info about uploading is here, but I noticed there's a 50mb limiit for the "basic" profile. I assume that's the free limit - https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202508836-Uploading-3D-Models